# How to connect SD card and battery to Pico?

Tags: sd-card, spi, battery, pi-pico, micropython

I have been looking into components I need for a MicroPython project. I needs to be battery powered and be able to read/write to a removable SD card.

For this, I have discovered SD breakout boards. They plug into SPI pins, and the VBUS and GND pins. The battery also connects to these 2 pins (40 and 38). How can I connect them both the the Pico - they use the same pins?

[image]

Comment: what is preventing you from connecting two wires to one pin?

Comment: I wasn't sure how many you could attach to one pin

Comment: think about this ... there are only two wires bringing power to your house and you do not power only one electrical device at a time

Comment: Thanks. Should I just wire them up in parallel to the battery